# How to perform this query in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have `Rooms` table and `Residents` table. every `Room` has different number of `Residents`, so my table is something like this:

#### Rooms

```
+-------------------+
| room_id | room_no |
+-------------------+
|   0001  |    5    |
|   0002  |    6    |
+-------------------+
```

#### Residents

```
+-------------------------------+
| user_id | user_name | room_id |
+-------------------------------+
|  0123   |   John    |  0001   |
|  0110   |   Gwen    |  0002   |
|  0020   |   Kim     |  0002   |
+-------------------------------+
```

So how to perform the query in `Controller` and then display it in `view` that would output like this?

```
Room 1 - Residents
+----------+
| 1 | John |
+----------+

Room 2 - Residents
+----------+
| 1 | Gwen |
| 2 | Kim  |
+----------+
```

Thanks in advance.

#### Note: I've already established proper associations my problem is on how to display it to the view as what I expected it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  need to first create an association in Room Model

```
var $hasMany=array('Resident');
```

After that in controller you can do this

```
$residents=$this->Room->find('all');
```

Comment: yes but when I do that the room keeps repeating. like for example `Room 1 = john`. `Room 2 = Gwen`, `Room2 = Kim`

Answer (score 0):

Set your Room model to [HasMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany) residents, and then in the [paginate call](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany) index action of your Room controller you will need to set recursive to 1.

In your Room index view you will need to loop through $room['Resident'] to show the residents.

Answer (score 0):

Find out more at: 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany 
. I used to debug in my .ctp this way.

```
<?php echo debug($rooms) ?>
```

You could see the associations before you could parse them. Or use the so called debugkit available at github